# Scripting: Skipping n files

Tags: shell-script

I'm trying to write a rather simple script, but can't find a
reasonable approach to skip some files.

I'd like to list all files somewhere with a given order. if that
listing contains more then (lets say) 10 files, I want to remove files
11-n but leave the first (or last) 10 in place.

/TLDR: How do I skip a fixed amount of files in a find/ls/whatever
result before piping into the next command

I want to sort all files (with given pattern) by name and if there are more than 10, remove these.

Answer (score 2):

Using `zsh`, the pattern

```
*(.[11,-1])
```

would match all names of regular files (not directory names etc.) in the current directory, sorting them by name (the default sort order), and would return all but the first ten of these names.

Testing:

```
$ touch file-{01..20}
$ ls
file-01 file-03 file-05 file-07 file-09 file-11 file-13 file-15 file-17 file-19
file-02 file-04 file-06 file-08 file-10 file-12 file-14 file-16 file-18 file-20
$ printf '%s\n' *(.[11,-1])
file-11
file-12
file-13
file-14
file-15
file-16
file-17
file-18
file-19
file-20
```

Would you want to *delete* these files:

```
$ rm *(.[11,-1])
$ ls
file-01 file-02 file-03 file-04 file-05 file-06 file-07 file-08 file-09 file-10
```

Note that this *requires* the `zsh` shell and that another shell, like `bash` would not understand the special type of globbing pattern used.

From some other shell, you could use

```
zsh -c 'rm *(.[11,-1])'
```

---

In `bash` you could do something like

```
names=( * )
printf '%s\n' "${names[@]:10}"
```

to list the filenames that you may want to remove, but there's no guarantee that the names listed are names of regular files, there may well be directory names too.  So you may want to loop:

```
for name in *; do
    if [ -f "$name" ]; then
        files+=( "$name" )
    fi
done

printf '%s\n' "${files[@]:10}"
```

This would also pick up names of symbolic links that points to regular files.

To remove these, use `rm "${files[@]:10}"`.

As with all operations that deletes data, you would test any solution on *copies* of real data before running them live.

Answer (score 0):

You have given us a very vague description of what you are trying to do so this answer will probably be equally as vague, but:

`head` and `tail` are designed for this purpose.

If you want to disregard everything but the first ten results use:

```
head -n 10
```

And to disregard everything but the last ten results use:

```
tail -n 10
```

Note: These only work if your results are separated by newlines.

Comment: `head` and `tail` are designed to give back a certain number of lines from the start or end of a _text file_.  And 10 is the default, so no need to specify that explicitly.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Or stdin, no?

Comment: Sure, but filenames with newlines and all that jazz.

Comment: "This filter displays the first count lines or bytes of each of the specified files, or of the standard input if no files are specified."

Comment: Yeah but OP did specify n files so I wanted to make sure to explain how/where to specify n

Comment: `*([1,10])` and `*([-10,-1])` will give you the first and last 10 names that the `*` glob expands to in `zsh`. That's IMHO far better than using `head` or `tail`. The only question is whether the user needs them sorted in any particular way.

Comment: Ok, I want to sort all files (with given pattern) by name and if there are more than 10, remove these.